# How can I call a method on loop in the same class?

Tags: android, methods

Suppose I have a method in a class and I need it to run continuously on a loop. 
How do I do that, without crashing the app.

I'm asking this because I have a method that gets the foreground activity on the device and I need to know every time the foreground activity is changed.

EDIT-

Here's my code to get the currently active Foreground Activity-

```
public void getForeground() 
{


    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String foreground = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), foreground, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

Now, I need to call this method so that it whenever there's a particular activity that has been opened (like Facebook, Messenger or Whatsapp), I know about it.

How do I do that?

Is there a simpler way apart from creating a custom listener or using a `ScheduledExecutorService` ?

Or if it can be done using the above mentioned ways, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a new thread to execute the method.

```
public void yourMethod() {
    doStuff();
    new Thread() {

      public void run() {
          yourMethod();
      }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Would this not overload the memory a lot? I mean, if I have to keep it active for a really long time, would it still work?

Comment: Well, the method simply gets the current activity which is in the foreground, which I guess, is not too time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

in your edited case you better go this way

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String foreground; 

Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{

@Override
public void run()

{

foreground = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), foreground, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}, 10000); //every 10 seconds
```

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't really work.
I put this whole code snippet in a function `getForeground()`, and then called it in the `OnCreate()` method. Is that how I'm supposed to do it?